# Show context menu on demand in Android

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

Consider an Android `ListView` with a context menu set up with `registerForContextMenu`. The context menu of a `ListView` item is shown when the user long taps over the item view.

Additionally, I would like to show the context menu when the user taps (not long taps) on the item (if certain conditions are met). Is it possible to do this? How?

Comment: Not clear what exactly the problem is. You mean, you've setup the ListView with registerForContextMenu and it's still not showing - or it is already?

Comment: I also want to show the context menu when the user taps (not long taps).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve this by browsing the Android source code. Here's what I did:

```
protected void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, int position) {
    final int start = adapterView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int index = position - start;
    final View childView = adapterView.getChildAt(index);
    if (childView != null) {
        adapterView.showContextMenuForChild(childView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes call performLongClick method from your click event and it should do it

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it if you already have long click set up through `onContextItemSelected()`.  Just create an `itemClickListener()` and add `performLongClick()` to it.  It worked for me, thanks!